# How To Catch The End of an Animation

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to run an animation and trap the end of the animation so I can do something at its conclusion.  I have been looking for examples online and this is what I have found.  Unfortunately, it is not compiling and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

discView is the view that is being animated.
animationDropSpeed is just a number
mainActivity is a pointer to the mainActivity object for my app.

```
        val discAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(discView, "translationY", 723f)
        discAnimator.setDuration(animationDropSpeed)

        discAnimator.addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener{
            override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animator?) {
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity,"Animation Started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        discAnimator.start()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention:  The compile error is with the word 'object' in the addListener call.  It says that 'object' is not abstract.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the listener by doing this

```
    ivSample.animation.setAnimationListener(
        object:Animation.AnimationListener{
            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
                TODO("not implemented")
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                TODO("not implemented") 
            }

            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                TODO("not implemented") 
            }
        }
    )
```

However, sometimes I prefer this way:

```
    ivSample.animate().translationY(723f).setDuration(500) // set duration
    ivSample.postDelayed({
        // TODO Doing my Job Here
    }, 600)  // set a delay more than the duration
```

This is more flexible on timing, and can access the parameters inside parent class because it's using lambda expression.

Choose one depend on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help.  Unfortunately, neither method worked.  I'm sure I am just not understanding something.

Comment: Never mind.  I forgot that with abstraction, you need to override all of the required methods, not just the one that you need.  It works now.  Many thanks.